# Discordjs API error whilst trying to banning a user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am attempting to program a ban command to be used by an administrator at a user who has broken the rules or has been naughty enough to be banned. When I ran the following code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const { MessageAttachment, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS","GUILD_MEMBERS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS", "DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING"], partials: ['CHANNEL',] })
const RichEmbed = require("discord.js");
const prefix = "!";



client.on("messageCreate", function(message) {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
  const args = commandBody.split(' ');
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  
  if (command === "news") {
    if (message.channel.type == "DM") {
      message.author.send(" ");
    }

  }
  if (command === "help") {
    message.author.send("The help desk is avaliable at this website: https://example.com/");
  }
});

client.on("messageCreate", function(message) {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
  const args = commandBody.split(' ');
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === "ping") {
    const timeTaken = Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp;
    message.channel.send(`Pong! ${timeTaken}ms.`);
  }
  if (command === "delete all messages") {
    const timeTaken = Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp;
    const code = Math.random(1,1000)
    message.channel.send(`Executing command. Verification Required.`);
    message.author.send(`Your code is the number ${code}.`)
    message.channel.send(`Please confirm your code. The code has been sent to your dms. Confirm it in here.`)
  }
  if (command === "ban") {
    const user = message.mentions.users.first().id
    message.guild.members.ban(user).then(user => {  
    message.channel.send(`Banned ${user.id}`);

}).catch(console.error);
}
});
client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN)
```

I ran into the following error whilst trying to test the command on a dummy acc.

```
DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/gwehuirw/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/gwehuirw/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14) {
  method: 'put',
  path: '/guilds/891083670314680370/bans/943680142004322326',
  code: 50013,
  httpStatus: 403,
  requestData: { json: { delete_message_days: 0 }, files: [] }
```

Could someone please help me with this? Thanks.

PS: I already had the necessary permissions for the bot to ban users. I also added the necessary intents for it to work. But I still am stuck.

Comment: In your `Intents` did you tried adding `GUILD_MEMBERS`?

Comment: I have done that now.

Comment: You still getting the same error after adding `GUILD_MEMBERS`?

Comment: Yeah. But I realised that I had to set roles to the user running the command.

Comment: Yes since you're using your dummy account. Add this code in your code files to return message to author when they don't have the role. `if(!message.member.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("You can't use this command.");`

Comment: If you're using discordjs v12 this should be the code: `if(!message.member.hasPermissions("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("You can't use this command.");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the user who was trying to ban a user needed to have certain permissions. I have finished working on the command. Thanks to everyone who had helped me through this mess!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `.id` when you are trying to get the user. Getting the id would be making you ban the string that is the id, not the user.

Comment: Try doing this anyways, since the error says that the bot has no such permission.

Comment: I gave the bot administrator privileges, however, even though I ran it, it still gave me the API error.

Comment: This has me stumped.

Comment: Wait... try removing the `.id` when getting the user,

Comment: I believe that if you try to get the id of the user you will be trying to ban a number or string, and not that user.

Comment: I removed the user ID, but I can't do anything as it says that I require permission.

Comment: Also, I noticed that you used `Math.random(1, 1000)`. That does not give a random number between 1 and 1000. (read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random). Try using `Math.floor(Math.random()*999+1)`. See if that works. Right now, it seems like something else than the permissions and your ban code is malfunctioning.

Comment: I do not think it is that part.

Comment: Still, you should change it, since it is possible that it is the part that is malfunctioning. Also, the random statement you used returns just plainly `Math.random()` without parameters.